# Why model->asGeode(); Returns NULL?

Tags: openscenegraph

I'm studying the OpenSceneGraph these days:

```
// Assumes the Cessna's root node is a group node.
osg::ref_ptr<osg::Node> model = osgDB::readNodeFile("cessna.osg");
osg::Group* convModel1 = model->asGroup(); // OK!
osg::Geode* convModel2 = model->asGeode(); // Returns NULL?
```

Why model->asGeode();   Returns NULL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at cessna.osg in a text editor:

```
Group {
  UniqueID Group_0
  DataVariance STATIC
  cullingActive TRUE
  num_children 1
  Geode {
    DataVariance DYNAMIC
    name "cessna.osg"
    cullingActive TRUE
    num_drawables 1
    Geometry {
```

you'll see that the top-level entity is a Group, not a Geode. You need to getChild() on the Node that comes back from readNodeFile, and then you should be able to asGeode() that.